# Correlating web requests between dotnet core services

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I've created a new application insights instance and set the instrumentation key environment variable for each of my 11 asp dotnet core 2.1 services. These services expose web methods that are called by each other in a nested fashion.

Application insights is enabled on startup by doing the following:

```
   services.UseApplicationInsights();
```

I can see that calls into all services are being loaded into Application Insights, and the direct dependencies are being displayed - these include database calls and calls to the other web services. My problem is that the calls to the other services do not seem to be correlated properly as I can't see a breakdown of what happened in the "child" service.

[image: AppInsightsScreenshot]

Although the second api call will have it's own dependencies listed if I view that separate request, its not possible to see them within the original parent request.

Is this the expected behaviour? Or am I expecting too much from the "out of box" telemetry.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Have you looked at ApplicationMap as well?

Comment: I have. It doesn't look quite as I'd expect. All of the services are contained in one component listed as "11 instances", and I can see the various DB calls on the outside. I believe this could be because all requests are routed by nginx and therefore all the individual services look like one application. However, I'm not sure if this would be affecting the correlation.

Comment: Are you using the same ikey for each of 11 apps? And have you run the app for quite some time - if not tried already, do let the app run for few seconds atleast.

Comment: Yes, the same instrumentation key is used for each app. I can see requests logged from all 11 apps and they've all been running for around a week.

Comment: Ok. This should have worked by default. I recommend open an issue in the product github: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/new

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. What exactly should work by default? Should I expect to see the breakdown of the "child" requests when viewing the "parent" request?